# Finding $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n^n$ where $a_n=\frac{(n!)^2}{(n+k)!(n-k)!}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> For each $k\in\mathbb N$, I am trying to find $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} a_n^n$ where $$a_n=\frac{(n!)^2}{(n+k)!(n-k)!}$$

Simplifying the factorials I have $$a_n=\frac{n(n-1)\ldots(n-k+1)}{(n+k)(n+k-1)\ldots(n+1)}$$

I tried to rewrite this as $$a_n=\frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)\ldots\left(1-\frac{k-1}{n}\right)}{\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{k-1}{n}\right)\ldots\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}$$

But all this tells me is that $a_n\to 1$.

Using Stirling's approximation, I think I also have $$a_n\sim \frac{n^{2n+1}}{(n+k)^{n+k+\frac{1}{2}}(n-k)^{n-k+\frac{1}{2}}}$$

Don't think this helps either. Any hint would be great.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee  -- no need for Stirling's approximation in this case. The answer presents itself from the OP's second formula for $a_n$ and Welanker's hint.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1338984/321264

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint We know that $\text{lim}_{n\to \infty} (1+\frac{x}{n})^n=e^x$ can you see how to proceed.

Comment: Yes of course. Can't believe I missed that.

Comment: It happens a few days ago I forgot e^((x)^x)=e^(x^2) ;)

Comment: @ArchisWelankar I think you mean $(e^x)^x$.

Comment: Yes @J.G. I'm still jinxed by it.

Answer (score 5):

We have $$a_n^n=\frac{\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}(1-j/n)^n}{\prod_{j=1}^k(1+j/n)^n}\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\to}\frac{\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}e^{-j}}{\prod_{j=1}^ke^j}=e^{-\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}j-\sum_{j=1}^kj}=e^{-k^2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

It was a good idea to use Stirling approximation; but for this, go to logarithms
$$a_n=\frac{(n!)^2}{(n+k)!(n-k)!}\implies \log(a_n)=2\log(n!)-\log((n+k)!)-\log((n-k)!)$$ So, using the logarithmic version of Stirling approximation and continuing with Taylor expansions for large values of $n$, you should get
$$\log(a_n)=-\frac{k^2}{n}+\frac{k^2}{2 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ Continue with Taylor using
$$a_n^n=e^{n \log(a_n)}=e^{-k^2}\left(1+\frac{k^2}{2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \right)$$ which shows the limit and also how it is approached.

Comment: Thank you. I think the term within parenthesis in your last line should be in the exponent.

Comment: @StubbornAtom. No because I continued with Taylor expansion.